# Entity Framework Core Multiple Many-to-many with linking table (join entity)

Tags: c#, join, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

How to add multiple many-to-many relationships between Entities in EF Core 5.x, with join entity (linking tables)?

What I what is two many-to-many relationships between Card and Game. One relationship is not a problem but two (or more) I'm not able to configure it correctly.

What's working at the moment for me is that I created two different classes DeckGameCard and TableGameCard (join entity), which forces EF to create two tables. The classes are the same except for the name. Is it possible to have only one class (join entity) and two linking tables in the database?

What I want is this:

```
public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<GameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<GameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
    ...
```

But at the moment this (the code below) is my solution (not optimal, because of code duplication in DeckGameCard and TableGameCard).

```
public class DeckGameCard
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}

public class TableGameCard
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}


public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<DeckGameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<TableGameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int CardIndex { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

public class Card : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Shape Shape { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Fill Fill { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int NrOfShapes { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<DeckGameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<TableGameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DeckGameCard>()
        .HasKey(x => new {x.GameId, x.CardId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<DeckGameCard>()
        .HasOne(gc => gc.Card)
        .WithMany(b => b.Deck)
        .HasForeignKey(gc => gc.CardId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DeckGameCard>()
        .HasOne(gc => gc.Game)
        .WithMany(g => g.Deck)
        .HasForeignKey(gc => gc.GameId);


    modelBuilder.Entity<TableGameCard>()
        .HasKey(x => new {x.GameId, x.CardId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<TableGameCard>()
        .HasOne(gc => gc.Card)
        .WithMany(b => b.OnTable)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CardId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TableGameCard>()
        .HasOne(gc => gc.Game)
        .WithMany(g => g.OnTable)
        .HasForeignKey(gc => gc.GameId);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using the EF Core 5.0 introduced [Shared-type entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#shared-type-entity-types-and-property-bags), but not sure it's worth since the type of an object no more uniquely identifies the entity type, so most if not all generic and non generic entity services (methods) of `DbContext` won't work, and you have to use the corresponding `DbSet<T>` methods, obtaining it using the `Set<T>(name)` overload. And there is no equivalent of `Entry` method, so you might have problems with change tracking in disconnected scenarios.

With that being said, here is how it can be done at model level.

Given the model similar to:

```cs
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<GameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<GameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
}

public class GameCard
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

it can be configured as follows:

```cs
modelBuilder.SharedTypeEntity<GameCard>("DeckGameCard", builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("DeckGameCard");
    builder.HasKey(e => new { e.GameId, e.CardId });
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Card).WithMany(e => e.Deck);
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Game).WithMany(e => e.Deck);
});

modelBuilder.SharedTypeEntity<GameCard>("TableGameCard", builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("TableGameCard");
    builder.HasKey(e => new { e.GameId, e.CardId });
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Card).WithMany(e => e.OnTable);
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Game).WithMany(e => e.OnTable);
});
```

or since the only difference is the entity (table) name and the corresponding collection navigation properties, the configuration can be factored out to a method similar to

```cs
static void GameCardEntity(
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder, string name,
    Expression<Func<Card, IEnumerable<GameCard>>> cardCollection,
    Expression<Func<Game, IEnumerable<GameCard>>> gameCollection,
    string tableName = null
)
{
    var builder = modelBuilder.SharedTypeEntity<GameCard>(name);
    builder.ToTable(tableName ?? name);
    builder.HasKey(e => new { e.GameId, e.CardId });
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Card).WithMany(cardCollection);
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Game).WithMany(gameCollection);
}
```

so the configuration becomes simply

```cs
GameCardEntity(modelBuilder, "DeckGameCard", c => c.Deck, g => g.Deck);
GameCardEntity(modelBuilder, "TableGameCard", c => c.OnTable, g => g.OnTable);
```

This should answer your concrete question. But again, make sure you understand the potential problems with it. And compare to "straight forward" solution achieving the same reusability with base *class* (not *entity*) without the above drawbacks, e.g.

```cs
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<DeskGameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TableGameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<DeskGameCard> Deck { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TableGameCard> OnTable { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GameCard
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}
public class DeskGameCard : GameCard { }
public class TableGameCard : GameCard { }
```

with only fluent configuration needed for composite PK

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DeskGameCard>().HasKey(e => new { e.GameId, e.CardId });
modelBuilder.Entity<TableGameCard>().HasKey(e => new { e.GameId, e.CardId });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the last solution with the base class (GameCard) and extending it for different relationships does the trick for me! Cleaver solution. Never thought of it this way, kept on struggling too long with the modelbuilder. 
The first solution has some drawback as you pointed out. I will try it out anyway (just out of curiosity). How do you know all the drawback of the SharedTypeEntity approach? I’m not able to find good documentation about it (except what’s new in EF Core 5, which is very short and hard to understand).

Comment: How do I know? Well, as you can imagine, it has been added by purpose, and in fact is used for many-to-many implicit join entity (a shared type `Dictionary<string, object>`). And the defects are visible just looking logically at the available APIs. For instance, the `Entry<T>` or `Entry(object)` methods - they receive `T` or `object` instance, but the shared entity needs name, and there is no such method. So you won't be able to get to the tracking state as with "normal" entities. Also context methods like `Add`, `Update`, `Attach`, `Remove` etc. Only `Set<T>` method has overload with name.